# dynamically query on dbset in DbContext class

Tags: entity-framework

Here is my DbContext class implementation:

```
    public partial class DXMvcApp : DbContext
{
    ...
    public virtual DbSet<TabMastCc> TabMastCcs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TabMastCo> TabMastCoes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TabMastCoCc> TabMastCoCcs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TabMastH> TabMastHs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TabMastHsCc> TabMastHsCcs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TabMastHsCo> TabMastHsCoes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TabMastHsCoCc> TabMastHsCoCcs { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have a string variable which represents the name of the DbSet. I want to dynamically query on the DbSet according to the string variable. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `DbSet` if you know the type (eg. by using `context.Set(typeof(TabMastCc))`).

If what you know is the name of the db set but not the type, what you can do is create a `Dictionary` mapping the name to the type in order for you to use the `context.Set` method.

Sample code:

```
var dbSets = new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
    { "TabMastCcs", typeof(TabMastCc) }
};

var dbSetName = "TabMastCcs";
var context = new YourContext();
var tabMastCcType = dbSets[dbSetName];
var tabMastCcDbSet = context.Set(tabMastCcType);
```